# Website Deployment Configuration Issues - 404 error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, visual-studio

I have created a website using VisualStudio 2013 to be used on an organizations intranet.  I have successfully deployed it (locally) such that the "Test" version is running on my desktop and allows users to test it by typing in my machine's IP address / application name.  This works well and so we decided to promote/deploy it to our production server.

We have IIS 8.5 installed on the server and finally got the VisualStudio 2013 deployment tool (powered by WebDeploy) to connect and deploy the website solution to the server.

However, when the window opens, it gives this error:

> **404 - File or directory not found.**
>
> The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I did some digging and found a few possible causes.

I have verified that the files do indeed exist on the server and in the places they should.

I'm not using IIS 6 so I don't know if the Web Service Extension of static vs dynamic content applies.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315122/http-error-404-file-or-directory-not-found-error-message-when-you-requ

Additionally, following the directions found in the link above, I cannot find a "Web service extension" node in my IIS 8 Manager. --Further, enforcing my opinion that (sense the linked site says IIS 6) this is not the issue.

The systems involved are Windows Server 2012 R2, Visual Studio 2013, aspx/c# Webforms, and IIS 8.5.

What might I be missing in either configuration files or the IIS manager to make these files (that are definitely on the server) visible to a user accessing the site?

**UPDATE:**

The full error code from the log file is:

> 404 3 50 203

203 at the end is most often, but some times its 265 or 187.

404.3 is MIME types, so checking that out.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried adding .aspx in the MIME mapping with `text/html` and with `application/xml`. Both of these populate the page but leave it wonky.

The spacing and formatting is off and the top of the page doesn't show the navigation bar defined in the Site.master page but rather:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Additionally, none of the links that work fine in the test version are displayed in the production version - I think this might be related to static page vs dynamic page, but while I can see the steps to creating a new Handler mapping, I'm not sure what settings I should use.

Comment: 404 has many sub-status codes, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 If you don't learn the actual you hit from IIS log files, it won't be easy to be on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for that link, and I finally found the full error code in the log file

Comment: @Lex Li -sorry forgot to at the notification in previous, I've updated the question after trying a few things thanks to your link

Comment: Can you use a tool like Telerik Fiddler to dive further into the field? With requests/responses captured, you should be able to see more on what triggered the 404.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten rid of the 404.3 error by adding .aspx application/xml and .master application/xml to the MIME Types list.